# Behringer footswitch

Tags: amplifiers

Sorry to start with a question but can anyone tell me what footswitch will work on my Behringer Euuropower 980s power mixer. I want to be able to switch between both effects channels and also to mute effects when speaking between numbers.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: @piiperi - unhelpfully, the manual says ' Use a standard footswitch'. I have maybe a dozen or more footswitches, half momentary, and half on/off. So no help there! But it'll be one or the other...

Comment: manual says..'use a dual footswitch to enable FX1and FXdependently.'....goes on to say....' the tip of 1/4" plug controls FX1 and the ring FX2'.. have no idea what this means

Comment: So the question is more like, what do tip and ring mean in a footswitch. You're looking for a dual i.e. two-channel footswitch with a tip-ring-sleeve i.e. TRS plug, like the manual says. There are some variations though. Maybe you'll just have to try one, they're not very expensive.